# access to iWork documents from iCloud enabled program

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, iwork

Is it possible to upload a document through the "Pages" section section of iCloud.com on a Mac then retrieve it through an iCloud query an iPad application I'm writing?

I have an app that is iCloud enabled and I've been following Paul Hegarty's tutorial at: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall but I'm not getting any results back from the query even though I have a couple documents in iCloud that I can open with the "Pages" app on my iPad. Any ideas of what may be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iCloud documents are sandboxed on a per-app basis. You can't access documents uploaded by any other app. It's not a single shared document space, it's one document space per app using the feature. So, your queries will only find documents that your app has already uploaded to the user's account, not those uploaded by Pages.